# System.Object[] After exporting MS Graph Powershell to CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've already tried using the join method but I am getting empty spaces after the export. Any ideas? Essentially this makes a 2 column table where it shows the groups each member is part of.

```
$user = Get-MgGroup -Filter "displayName eq 'xx-xxx-xx'"
$user.Id

# Get the IDs of the groups the user is a member of
$groupIds = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $user.Id | ForEach-Object {$_.Id}

# Get members of each group
$results = foreach ($groupId in $groupIds) {
    
    $group = Get-MgUser -UserId $groupId #Retrive the data of each user
    $displayName = $group.DisplayName
    $memberOf = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId $groupId | select * -ExpandProperty additionalProperties | Select-Object {$_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]} #get the memberof each user and filter by displayname
  
    
    # Create a custom object with properties
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Employee = "$displayName Member of:"
        Group = $memberOf -join "`r`n"
    }
    
   
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "/xx/xx/0.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: may you share the results of `$memberOf = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId $groupId` ?

Comment: very confusing how you keep using variable `$user` when it references a group and variable `$group` when it references user(s)...

Answer (score 0):

> But I am getting empty spaces after the export. Any ideas? Essentially, this makes a two-column table where it shows the groups each member is part of.

You can use the modified code below to export the `memberof` groups name in the CSV file.

**Script:**

```
$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "displayName eq 'xxx'"
$groupId = $group.Id

# Get the IDs of the members of the group
$memberIds = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $groupId | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }

# Get data for each member
$results = foreach ($memberId in $memberIds) {
    
    $user = Get-MgUser -UserId $memberId # Retrieve the data of each user
    $displayName = $user.DisplayName
    
    # Get the groups that the user is a member of
    $groups = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId $memberId | ForEach-Object {
        $_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]
    }

    # Create a custom object with properties
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Employee = "$displayName Member of:"
        Group = $groups -join ","
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "xx\xxx\sample.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above script retrieves the members of a group named "Demovenkat" and exports their display names and the names of the groups they are members of. It uses the `Get-MgUserMemberOf` command to retrieve the necessary data (CSV file) and the `Export-Csv` command to export the data to a CSV file.

**Output:**
[image]